# Car Dealer Management Software

Tags: c#

For learning purposes Im thinking of Creating a management software for car dealers, but before I get into the designing/planning stage im gathering requirements. Would anyone be able to add something to my current req list?

Here is what I have so far

1. Different logins (Admin, Mechanic, Car Cleaner)
2. Possibility to Add used and new cars to th system
3. When Car is sold move it to sold section with all the details
4. Possibility to book a viewing/test drive
5. Check current stock
6. Reports such as, best selling cars by make

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not forget the [Non-functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) requirements. The [functional requirement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_requirement) page is also a starting point for reading more about requirements.

Comment: System requirements is a pretty subjective thing.  I don’t think asking the internet for answers is really going to get you far

Comment: Yes you are right, but for a simple app i dont see why asking the „internet” is not a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements looks good for a basic CRUD app , don't forget to add the update section for users and cars, and maybe you want to add a view system for the cars filtering by type or brand or price, make the app secure .